# how to decode a USB signal on a breadboard

Tags: usb, breadboard, dip

I would like read binary data that is not formatted.  Is there any DIP to decode it?

Comment: Your best bet is probably a USB-RS232 UART like the FT232, and decode the RS232 data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB is a high level protocol, a high speed/frequency encoded differential signal, composed of multiple formatted packets. It cannot be easily decoded, especially not on a breadboard.